# Custom events in Google Analytics 4 for Ajax search

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a search feature on my website. I am sending the textbox value to a controller using Ajax and reading the response. I want to track the text box value in Google Analytics 4. I have created a custom event but confused about what will be my matching condition (parameter name, operator and value)?

[image]

```
window.gtag('event','search_keyword',{
  search_term_input : $('#txt-search').val(),
  country_code : 'UK'
});
```

The request is reaching GA4 and the event is visible in the Real-time tracking dashboard. I have created a custom dimension for the search_keyword event and when generating the report the search term is not available. The report displays "not set".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work as I don't have a setup to test it on atm.

In the Web Data Stream Settings, try adding the cd parameter name in the GA4 Site Search settings in the Additional Query Parameters field
[image]